# How does broadcasting work for multiplication between an array of numbers and a block matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have an array of n floats say `[a, b, ..., z]` and a block matrix `[II, X, Y, Z]` where `II`, `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are all 2x2 matrices.

```py
II = np.identity(2, dtype=complex)
X = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]], dtype=complex)
Y = np.array([[0, -1j], [1j, 0]], dtype=complex)
Z = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]], dtype=complex)
```

My question is how do I multiply the array of floats `[a, b, ..., z]` to the block matrix `[II, X, Y, Z]` such that it broadcasts into:

```
[[a*II, a*X, a*Y, a*Z]
 [b*II, b*X, b*Y, b*Z]
 ....................
 [z*II, z*X, z*Y, z*Z]]
```

with a shape of `(n,4,2,2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make sure that the dimensions match up. Here is an example:

```
mult = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
conc = np.array([II,X,Y,Z])
res = conc.reshape(((1,)+conc.shape)) * mult.reshape((len(mult),1,1,1))
print(res.shape)
```

Output:

```
(5, 4, 2, 2)
```